# Moving for divisors inducing the same map on homology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a complex projective variety and let $H$ be a hypersurface section of $X$ which contains all singular points. By Lefschetz hyperplane theorem the inclusion of $H$ in $X$ induces isomorphism on $i$-th homology, for some fixed value of $i$ that is small enough (less than the dimension of $H$). Let $p$ be a singular point which is also on $H$.

We define an equivalence relation on subvarieties of $X$. We say $D\sim D'$ if $D\hookrightarrow X$ and $D' \hookrightarrow X$ induce maps on the $i$-homology such that their image are same in $H_i(X)$.

- Is it possible to find an equivalent to $H$ like $H'$ such that $p$ is not on $H'$?
- How about if enlarge the point $p$ and instead we consider some small enough dimensional closed subset that we want $H'$ (equivalence to $H$) to cut this subset in closed subset of codimension 1?
- If the answers are positive how about we replace the projectivity condition with quasi-projectivity and the homology by Borel-Moore homology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the variety is a surface a single orbifold point and $c_1.H $ is a non-integer rational number (This does happen, for example I think there are log del Pezzo's with $c_1^2$ non-integer). Then one cannot move it off the singular points since this would imply the above intersection number is an integer.

Comment: Thanks you fir your comment. I think by moving you are assuming some form of adequate equivalence like rational equivalence, but I mean very loosely. I will edit the problem to reflect this,

Comment: It also provides a counter example to this looser form of equivalence. This product $c_1.H$ is an honest cup product in the singular cohomology ring of the orbifold.  In fact it shows that any singular cycle in the homology class of $H$ has to pass through the orbifold point., so it is not really about subvarieties.